# How do I call a method in ir.rule domain in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'd like to create a **record** rule for my app.

**Here is my XML:**

```xml
<record model="ir.rule" id="ir_rule_something"> 
    <field name="name">something</field> 
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_something"/> 
    <field name="domain_force">[('agent','in',function_that_return_list_of_ids)]</field> 
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/> 
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/> 
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/> 
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/> 
</record>
```

I would like the **`function_that_return_list_of_ids`** to return a list of **`id`**. Where do I put the method and how do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be for you to override `_eval_context`  or `_eval_context_for_combinations` in `ir.rule` itself.

```
class MyIrRule(models.Model):
    _inherit ="ir.rule"

    @api.model
    def _eval_context(self):
        context = super(MyIrRule,self)._eval_context()
        context.update(function_of_ids=function_of_ids)
```

In this example, `function_of_ids` is not a method but a simple function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found out another method to call a function from ir.rule.
Here it is.

```
<record id="manager_asterisk_cdr_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Manager Asterisk CDR rule</field>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="1"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_barrier_manager')])]"/>
    <field name="model_id" ref="asterisk_base.model_asterisk_cdr"/>
    <field name="domain_force">user.manager.get_cdr_domain()</field>
</record>
```

The main part is:

```
<field name="domain_force">user.manager.get_cdr_domain()</field>
```

And here is the function:

```
@api.multi
def get_cdr_domain(self):
    # Used from facility_manager/security.xml to filter CDR records
    facility_ids = [f.id for f in self.facilities]
    barriers = self.env['barrier.barrier'].search(
                                        [('facility', 'in', facility_ids)])
    numbers = []
    for b in barriers:
        # Add barrier access phones
        numbers.extend([a.number for a in b.access_phones])
        # Add panels GSM number
        numbers.extend(
            [p.gsm_number for p in b.call_panels if p.gsm_number])
        # Add panels SIP number
        numbers.extend(
            [p.sip_number for p in b.call_panels if p.sip_number])
    # Add keys of type=phone
    key_numbers = [k.number for k in self.env[
        'barrier.resident_key'].search([
                                       ('facility', 'in', facility_ids),
                                       ('key_type', '=', 'phone')])]
    numbers.extend(key_numbers)
    domain = ['|', ('src', 'in', numbers), ('dst', 'in', numbers)]
    return domain
```

Also when you add new records to the models requested from the function you need to clear cache:

```
self.env['ir.rule'].clear_cache()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Max, can you upvote my question, the -1 annoys me.